# SBT project refresh failing in IntelliJ IDEA with "Access is denied" error

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, java-8

I have recently migrated a *Scala* project over to *IntelliJ IDEA* (v13.1.4) from *Eclipse*, and I'm seeing an unusual error when I start *IDEA*:

```
SBT 'myproject' project refresh failed:
    Error: Cannot run program "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0" (in directory "C:\src\myproject"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

Everything seems to work OK otherwise, and I have no problems executing `SBT` manually from the command line.

I'm running the `idea64.exe` executable on *Windows 7 Professional 64-bit*, with a *Java 8 64-bit JDK* that is installed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0`.

I have also configured the `IDEA_JDK_64` environment variable to point to this Java 8 JDK (with the value `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0`, so that it contains no spaces); `JAVA_HOME` is set to the same value, and the JDK is also included on my `Path` (as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`). The project itself is configured to use the same Java 8 JDK.

However, the error appears to indicate that IDEA is trying to execute the `jdk1.8.0` directory, rather than a program within the JDK installation.

Any suggestions for why I'm seeing this error?

Comment: If I specify a custom _JVM_ for _SBT_ to use in the global settings, then I get the above error (I've tried selecting the `jre`, `bin` and `jre\bin` subdirectories without any luck either - and it's not possible to select a file). However, if I use the default _JVM_, then it works OK, and the error goes away. I'll check the _JetBrains_ site/_Scala_ plugin site to see if this is a bug...

Comment: Discussion raised in _JetBrains_ [Scala forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/456414?tstart=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might know, I think it is a bug of Scala Plugin.

This bug has been fixed already.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7481

Comment: Thanks for the update. I couldn't figure out how to report this as a bug, so I raised it as a forum topic - which, of course, had no replies. :-(